# Block connections to localhost by non-localhost webpages on Firefox

Tags: networking, firefox, localhost

I am migrating to Firefox from Safari and noticed that websites (ANY website) that I visit has permission to attempt to make connections to localhost ports. I'm concerned with the privacy implications of this and want to block any connection to localhost, 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, etc. for any website that is NOT also localhost (because I also need to use localhost for web development, and I want connections to not be blocked when the hostname is also localhost. Is there a way to configure Firefox to block such connections? Safari already does this natively.

Comment: I'm pretty sure in most OS's. any program can connect to any port on localhost (127.x.y.z). its up to the program that owns the port being connected to to determine whether and if that is an issue. as for 0.0.0.0, listeners defined on it are literally asking for connections from anyone. reconfigure the service that established those listeners if you dont want them accessible to any system that has access to the port.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I want either. There may be listeners I am not aware of. For example, there was a time Zoom installed an insecure web server giving access to peoples webcams. I want to protect against these potential insecure servers being accessed, and I also want to prevent being profiled based on programs running on my computer. (For example, any website can detect whether I have Discord open by checking if there is a ws server on port 6463)